# Native SQL(written in xml) result set mapping to POJO(annotation based)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-native-query

I'm working on a Spring MVC legacy project and currently, we are upgrading the spring(2) and hibernate(2) to latest version. Previously in the project there are sql-query and entity mappings are done in the `XML` files and we are upgrading the entity mapping from `XML` to `annotation` based. The problem is occurring for the entity mappings that are done on the basis of the result set of a query. I want to keep the query in the XML files only(**as these are very very big queries performing joins on 4-5 tables)** and just change the entity mapping. Previously the entity mapping is done like this

```
<class name="ClassName" table="x" mutable="false">
    <id name="id" column="id_col">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
        <property name="linkId"  ....

</class>
```

How will I annotate `table='x'` in the annotation based mapping?

**P.S** `table="x"` is not an example it is written in that way only in XML mapping and there is no table named x in DB

Comment: erm.. `@Table`?

Comment: Nope it's not that easy

Comment: Could you perhaps try to add some more context as it's not very clear what the issue is. What troubles do you have when mapping the entities?

Comment: It gives me null pointer exception at run time

Comment: Sorry but there is not sufficient info to fix a NPE with the information given

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class ClassName {
}
```

In native Query in xml

```
<sql-query name="findQuery">
   <return alias="ClassName" class="ClassName"/>
   select * from x
</sql-query>
```